# How to programattically edit a document / sheet in Quip?

Tags: quip

I've read the documentation but I still don't know if the following is possible:

I have a regular Quip doc with a table/spreadsheet in it. In it I have a column with an "ID". In another column I have "status" (in progress / done).

I want to create `<something>` that would allow me to:

1. Do an HTTP request to an external service (say, Jira) with the the value in the ID column
2. Populate the "status" column with the results from #1.

Is there anything I can do to accomplish this? I've tried creating a user script (tampermonkey / greasemonkey script) but due the complexity of React's runtime I don't think it's possible. Please let me know if it actually is.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Q4S? You can use the Salesforce record live app where the information flow is bidirectional and you can do a call out to your external service from there.

Comment: No, I don't know what Q4S is. Could you link and explain, and maybe point to an example? Thanks a lot